# Could not find a part of the path '..\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.4.4.1\lib\net46\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Recently I updated my Nuget Packages for my ASP.NET Web API project (.**NET 4.7.1**) and build it successfully without any issues. However, when I tried to **check-in** the solution to my **VSTS source control**. I got the following error:

**Could not find a part of the path '..\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.4.4.1\lib\net46\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'.**

This looks like a bug to me and I couldn't find a way to solve this issue while Googling etc...Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this this is what I did.

I first removed the version 4.4.1 and added the version (previous) 4.4.0 and took the backup of the version 4.4.0 and then re-added the version 4.4.1. Backup is necessary because only one version can be present in the packages folder by Nuget.

**Install-Package System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource -Version 4.4.0**

**Install-Package System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource -Version 4.4.1**

Finally I copied the entire 4.4.0 folder to the packages folder and **checked-in** the solution successfully. Now there are two versions (folders) are present in the packages folder locally (but 4.4.1 is used in the application).

This may be helpful for some but is there **any other way** to solve this issue?